# Help to understand a Lemma about 'supremum of a family of measures'

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I read the following Lemma from a paper but I can't understand the proof. Please help!

> Lemma: Let $\mu$ be a positive measure defined on the family of open
>   subsets of $\Omega$, which is super-additive on open sets with
>   disjoint compact closure. (Here $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ is open
>   bounded with Lip boundary). Let $\lambda$ be a positive measure on
>   $\Omega$, let $\phi_i$ be positive Borel functions such that
>   $\mu(A)\geq \int_A \phi_i d\lambda$ for all open sets $A$ and let
>   $\phi(x)=\sup_i \phi_i(x)$.  Then $\mu(A)\geq \int_A\phi d\lambda$ for
>   all open sets $A$.

and here is the proof. It is short.

> Proof: By the regularity of the measures $\phi_i\lambda$,
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_A \phi d\lambda &= \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\int_{B_i}\phi_i d\lambda:\,(B_i)\text{ Borel partition of }A,\,k\in \mathbb N\right\}\\
> & = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\int_{K_i}\phi_i d\lambda:\,(K_i)\text{ disjoint compact subsets of }A,\,k\in \mathbb N\right\}\\
> & = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\int_{A_i}\phi_i d\lambda:\,(A_i)\text{ disjoint open subsets of }A,\,k\in \mathbb N\right\}\leq \mu(A)
> \end{align*}

Here is my questions...

1. why the first equation holds? what does Borel partition means? I tried to search online but there no information about Borel partition...
2. why can we change $B_i$ to $K_i$ to $A_i$ but without losing the equality?
3. why only finitely many $B_i$'s? Should it be at least countably many?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

1. A Borel partition is simply a subdivision of $\Omega$ in disjoint Borel subsets.
2. Because our measures are [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure).
3. No, Lebesgue integral is (or at least can) be defined as the sup of the integrals of simple functions, where simple functions are measurable functions which only assume a finite number of values.